# Basic Papa Parse Issue

Tags: jquery, papaparse

I'm getting the following UndetectableDelimiter error in the console when trying to parse CSV files with Papa Parse:

[image: Error Message in Object]

The data array does not contain anything. Test2.csv is a comma delimited file created and saved in Excel. It has 4 columns and 4 rows. The file is located in the same folder as the HTML file. See the CSV file here: https://filebin.net/f9kgeercbsw775lv

[The CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGz6n.png)

```js
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.1.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>

<script>
 $(function() { 
  
 var results = Papa.parse('test2.csv', {
  delimiter: "",  
    newline: "", 
  complete: function(results) {
    console.log(results);
    data = results.data;
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you give a sample of `Test2.csv` (see [mcve])? What happens if you specify the appropriate `delimiter` and `newline` rather than relying on auto-detection?

Comment: CSV file should be downloadable here: https://a.uguu.se/8y6rvk3AlP8t_test2.csv. The code above shows comma separated delimiter and newline I believe already.

Comment: Please put it **in the question**, let's not train people to click unfamiliar links.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. Hope the post meets guidelines now.

Comment: No, I mean a sample of the file itself, not just putting links in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're specifying an empty string as the delimiter. Set your delimiter to comma and you'll at least avoid that error.

`delimiter: ',',`

**Edit:** The only way I've used `Papa.parse()` is with a file upload. Here's how:

```html
<label for="theCSV">CSV file:</label>
<input type="file" id="theCSV" name="theCSV" />


<div id="results"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.1.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    var csv;

    $("#theCSV").change(function(e) {
      Papa.parse(e.target.files[0], {
        download: true,
        header: true,
        delimiter: ',',
        skipEmptyLines: true,
        error: function(err, file, inputElem, reason) {
          $('#results').append('Error: ' + err + ' : ' + reason + '<br>');
          return false;
        },
        complete: function(results) {
          $('#results').append(JSON.stringify(results.data) + '<br>');
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Duh! Thanks! That got rid of the error. But the array is still empty! Any ideas?

Comment: Give me a minute. I'll find where I've used it papaparse before.

Comment: So, according to the help docs, a file is a file object obtained from the DOM. https://www.papaparse.com/docs.html#local-files    I just want to give it a filename? How would I pass in a file from the DOM?

Comment: Thanks @thingEvery. I noticed that a lot of the examples use the file upload methodology. But what if I just need to parse an already existing local CSV file? How can I pass in an Object from the DOM?

Comment: @Learning2Prgrm You should mark my answer correct and post a new question about that.